# jQuery .slideDown() .hide() .show() not working on iPhone (Safari Mobile)

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I am encountering an issue with jQuery slideDown(), show(), hide() functionality on a mobile site. The functionality works on desktop versions of Safari, Chrome, and FF.  It also works on Safari with user agent set to iPhone.  However, when loading the page iPhone (Safari) the functionality does not work...when you select the link that should toggle the show/hide nothing happens (no error).  The site is using the following versions of jQuery & jQuery mobile:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Below is a sample of the HTML being referenced in the script along with the jQuery script:

[HTML Sample]

```
<div id="body" class="body-content default-copy">
    Sed eget vehicula dui. Ut feugiat, augue ac ullamcorper varius, tellus nunc aliquam...
    <br>
    <p class="body-content-more default-copy-hidden-more" style="float: right; width: 150px;
        text-align: right; text-decoration: none;">
        <a href="#" class="see_more" style="text-decoration: none;">&gt; See More</a></p>
    <br>
</div>
<div id="body" class="body-content default-copy-full" style="display: none;">
    Sed eget vehicula dui. Ut feugiat, augue ac ullamcorper varius, tellus nunc aliquam
    metus, sed cursus magna felis vel enim. Maecenas elementum, odio eget gravida suscipit,
    felis diam aliquam magna, ut vestibulum augue magna in tortor. Sed nibh justo, iaculis
    ac lacinia non, pellentesque eu erat. Nam mollis, urna at gravida sodales, felis
    nisl hendrerit velit, non ornare sapien purus ut orci. Donec nec augue libero, eu
    tincidunt ipsum. Pellentesque at lacus augue, et egestas enim. Quisque ac dui mi,
    et eleifend nulla. Integer quis elit eget nisl fermentum blandit at in eros. Vestibulum
    a est nisl. Maecenas eget nisl arcu, quis tincidunt risus. Aliquam erat volutpat.
    Nullam lacinia venenatis libero, non imperdiet turpis vestibulum eget. Donec fermentum
    ullamcorper elementum.<br>
    <p class="body-content-more default-copy-hidden-less" style="float: right; width: 150px;
        text-align: right; text-decoration: none;">
        <a href="#" class="see_less" style="text-decoration: none;">&gt; See Less</a></p>
    <br>
</div>
```

​

[jQuery Script]

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.see_more').click(function () {

        //divs to hide
        $(".body-content.default-copy").hide();
        $("p.body-content-more.default-copy-hidden-more").hide();

        //divs to show
        $(".body-content.default-copy-full").slideDown(500); 
        $("p.body-content-more.default-copy-hidden-less").show();

    });

    $('.see_less').click(function () {

        //divs to hide
        $(".body-content.default-copy-full").hide();
        $("p.body-content-more.default-copy-hidden-less").hide();

        //divs to show
        $(".body-content.default-copy").slideDown(500);
        $("p.body-content-more.default-copy-hidden-more").show();

    });

});​
```

Here's a jsfiddle link, as well, if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/GwfJ8/

Anyone encountered this problem before or have any suggestions?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Additional Info:  So I decided to enable Safari Debug Console (on iphone) and it detected 1 error [HTML: Error - Viewport argument key "target-densitydpi" not recognized and ignored].  However, even with the error message the jQuery script functionality works perfectly after enabling Debug Console!  If I disable Debug Console & clear website data the script stops working again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Kiran & sachin kulkarni for taking time to look at this and your response.  The issue turned out to be related to jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation option.  It was enabled by default and was causing issues with my script (and some other functionality).  Apparently this is a common issue & seasoned jQuery mobile developers commonly disable this option first thing.  Adding the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        // jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation does not work in all cases (e.g.,
        // when navigating from a mobile to a non-mobile page), especially when going back, hence disabling it.
        $.extend($.mobile, {
            ajaxEnabled: false
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

...prior to jQuery mobile script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

... disables Ajax navigation.  After disabling Ajax navigation the issue was resolved...my original script as posted here worked without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is you are using $(document).ready() which shouldn't be used according to this: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html.

`Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will give that a try and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to Attach an event handler to click events for the selector
('.see_less' / '.see_more').

here is the code.

```
$(".see_more").live("click", function(){
        //divs to hide
        $(".body-content.default-copy").hide();
        $("p.body-content-more.default-copy-hidden-more").hide();

        //divs to show
        $(".body-content.default-copy-full").slideDown(500); 
        $("p.body-content-more.default-copy-hidden-less").show(); 
}); 



$(".see_less").live("click", function(){ 

     //divs to hide
        $(".body-content.default-copy-full").hide();
        $("p.body-content-more.default-copy-hidden-less").hide();

        //divs to show
        $(".body-content.default-copy").slideDown(500);
        $("p.body-content-more.default-copy-hidden-more").show();

});
```

you can refer link to attach event handler http://api.jquery.com/live/